# Reloading an image after zooming in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a group, inside of which is an image.  I've got code working so you can zoom with the mouse wheel.  When the zooming stops, I reload the image, in a larger size.  I add the new image to the group ( the old image is still part of the group ) and then I do this:

```
img.remove();
img.destroy();
imgNew.moveToTop();
imgNew.offsetX = offset.x;
imgNew.offsetY = offset.y;
```

At the end of this code, my old image disappears and the new one is not visible.  It has a position that is sane, and it is the child of my group.  It has exactly the size I expect it to have ( it's absolute position is 0,0 and it's size is bigger than my canvas ).  I've turned off clipping, so if it was visible anywhere, I'd see it.  I've changed the position in the debugger, and called draw() on the canvas, the layer and the group.  I have dragging code and I've dragged the drag control ( which is still there ) every where I can.  I've also changed my code to just add the new image to the top level layer instead of the lower down group.

I should mention in case it's relevant, the image is coming from a WebAPI RESTful service, and the size is passed in, so the image URLs are different for the two images.

I simply cannot find my image !!! What should I do next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

[KineticJS - How to Change Image src on Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213309/kineticjs-how-to-change-image-src-on-button-click)

answered my question.  Short version: there's a setImage method so you can load a new image, call setImage() and it gets replaced.